# Calling JavaScript function defined in a PartialView after AJAX request completes?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, ajax.beginform

Here is my partial view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onComplete() { .... }
</script>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm( new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "onComplete" })
{
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
}
```

When I submit form and receive response, I get the JavaScript error:

```
ReferenceError: onComplete is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution:
declare function as

```
window.onComplete(){...}
```

and call it

```
window.onComplete
```

It seems function has another scope.